# Approve the contract to send the Tokens

Tags: solidity, ethereumjs, web3j

**error is coming 'token is not own' what i did.**

**I  approved the contract to spend tokens from the token owners account lets say account  A approved the contract address**

```
function _setApprovalForAll(
         address owner,
        address operator,
        bool approved
    ) internal virtual override {
        emit ApprovalForAll(owner, operator, approved);
    }
```

**After that i switch the Account to B user to spin the spinner and win tokens which contract will send to B user on A behalf**

```
function winNft (uint winningNft ) internal  returns(bool){
    for(uint i=0; i < winningNft; i++){
        uint256 winningId =  block.timestamp % ((tokens.length-1) - min + 1) + min;
      _transferFrom(address(masterWallet),msg.sender,tokens[winningId]);

        tokens[winningId]=tokens[tokens.length-1];
        tokens.pop();
    }
   return true
    }
```

Comment: Can you share the whole contract? In particular the implementation of `_transferFrom`. The implementation of `_setApprovalForAll` doesn't do any change to the contract. The [OpenZeppelin implementation](https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/master/contracts/token/ERC721/ERC721.sol#L368-L376) stores changes in a mappgin.

Comment: Thanks for help .

i fix my problem by making the separate contract to allow contract to spend tokens on token holders behalf.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i fix my problem by making the separate contract to allow contract to spend tokens on token holders behalf.